# Who is telling sons of Ragnar about Ragnar's death?

Tags: vikings

Who is the person with a single eye who is informing sons of Ragnar about Ragnar's death?
In Vikings season 4 episode 15.

Comment: this question could use a bit more fleshing out as to why you don't know who this character is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ScreenerTV knows the answer](http://screenertv.com/television/vikings-black-cloaked-figure-odin-explanation/):

> But even with these events, there’s a single solitary question that
>   has to be on the mind of every “Vikings” fan: Who is the one-eyed man
>   cloaked in black (Andre Eriksen) that brought the news of his death to
>   the sons of Ragnar Lothbrok? He appeared briefly in a previous
>   episode, but was merely credited as “Black Cloaked Figure.”
>
> Clearly though, he’s a higher power that is able to be in many places
>   at once, coming to Ragnar’s sons when they need him most. So who is
>   he? Luckily, **creator Michael Hirst has shed a little light on that
>   question.**
>
> [During a Q&A on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Vikings/photos/a.317139428390938.64567.258436810927867/1037507133020827/?type=3&permPage=1), **Hirst revealed that the man in question is
>   “Odin, the All-Father.”** Typically depicted as only having one eye,
>   Odin is the most prominent of the Norse gods worshiped by the Vikings.

[MoviePilot also weighs in](https://moviepilot.com/p/vikings-one-eyed-man/4178895):

> But the strange figure on the boat is no stranger at all. In fact, he
>   made an appearance in the very first episode of *Vikings* — in the first
>   scene, no less. So who is it?
>
> In the first season of *Vikings*, Ragnar is surveying a battle scene
>   littered with bodies when he spots a strange figure in the distance,
>   selecting fallen warriors to ascend to valhalla.
>
> **This is Odin, a god who the vikings believed ruled valhalla and was
>   one of the most iconic and revered figures in norse mythology. He was
>   commonly associated with ravens, and gave his eye in exchange for
>   knowledge.**
>
> So how do we know the man on the boat is Odin? Well, he's got one eye,
>   and his ship is surrounded by a swarm of ravens. He also appears
>   directly after Ragnar's death, linking him to the viking's tragic
>   demise.